# Can I do data visualization with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, data-visualization, web-deployment-project

Basically i want it to import data from a SQL database and Display it as graphs. Having said that i also want it to be dynamic,responsive as in the users should have filtering options. Any leads would be definitely helpful.
Please note that i am just a beginner with drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, But I recommend you to work on your own framework. Or even you can use some data visualization framework

Maybe this one is useful for you if you want to do it on your own:
http://www.sitepoint.com/twelve-javascript-libraries-data-visualization/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Drupal for that?

I would make some PHP script which would read SQL and generate image out of that data, by using GD or ImageMagic lib. I guess you know that PHP can shoot out image file header and dynamically generate image, on fly. That PHP script could also read filter parameters to have influence on generated image.